# How to create a progress dialog when switching the webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say when user click on a button and the webpage will direct to another webpage, between the loading and waiting of the webpage, I want to show a progress dialog (something like a animated spinner) and it will disappear after another webpage is fully loaded.

How am I going to do such thing by using HTML, Javascript and CSS? At the first webpage I know how to do but I have no idea how to show the progress dialog immediately when the second webpage is being loaded. Any idea? Example is most welcome!

Comment: This would only be possible through the use of AJAX. I.e. dynamically replacing the page's content with some other content. If the page were to actually change, you wouldn't be able to display a spinner until it had loaded.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you plan to redirect the user to another web page, you won't be able to show a loading dialog that persists from one page to the other. But what you can do is, when your linked webpage begins loading, first display some sort of "loading" indicator while your page resources load. How you implement this depends on what exactly is 'loading'. What is loading on the second webpage that is requiring you to have a progress bar? Such as a long web request, etc?

Comment: Mmm, you talk about a [progress dialog](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/images/progressdialog.png), but you want a [spinner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bdrWh.png)

Comment: It might help if you told us why you wanted to do this. People are generally used to pages not loading instantly; I don't see why you'd want to hide the page until it finishes loading.

Comment: @Bondye Sorry, I think what I want is a spinner.

Comment: @user1618143 Actually I want to block user to click on any other button/link (or etc.) when the request is being processed. Another reason is I want to use this mechanism in mobile development, the spinner can notice user that something is running so they would't think that app is freezing.

Comment: So why do you need anything on the second page, then? You said you know how to handle page 1 already.

Comment: You could use jQuery and when you click on a link or submit a form, you could [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) a [spinner](http://preloaders.net/). And otherwhise, thus when the dom is ready loading, fadeOut the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do if you use some jQuery
With a file structure like this:

- firstpage.html (contains link to other page)
- secondpage.html
- js (directory)

  - yourscript.js
  - jquery.js

Include `<script src="js/jquery.js></script>` and`<script src="js/yourscript.js></script>` in secondpage.html.
Add this to secondpage.html:

```html
<div id="loading_screen"></div>
```

And the CSS

```css
#loading_screen {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: /*any image, color, w/e*/;
}
/* don't forget that if you want the loading screen to fit full page,
* you'll have to set body, html to margin, padding = 0 & width, height = 100% */
```

In yourscript.js (the important part):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var loadingscreen = $('#loading_screen');
var timeToLoad = 1000; /* in miliseconds, 1000 = 1 second */

setTimeOut(function() {
loadingscreen.hide();
// or if you prefer removing it completely from the DOM: loadingscreen.remove();
}, timeToLoad)

});
```

Comment: What's the point of this? By my reading, it just sticks a "loading" message over top of the second page, which (depending on the browser) won't typically appear until the page has already loaded. And it's a fixed time from the html finishing its load until it vanishes, so it won't even properly hide unloaded images and such.

Comment: Yes, the drawback is of course that you have to estimate the time necessary for loading yourself, but what you're asking is just not possible, it'd be an integrated browser solution. I don't know AJAX welle enough, maybe..And you could initiate the loading screen first , then `loadingscreen.onload()`